# For what value of $K$ are the points $A(1, -1)$, $B(K/2, K/3)$, and $C(4, 1)$ collinear?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

> For what value of $K$ are the points $A(1, -1)$, $B(K/2, K/3)$, and $C(4, 1)$ collinear?

The equation of line $AC$ is $2x-3y=5$. But the point $B$ doesn't satisfy the equation.

Comment: Is there, perhaps, a unique value of $K$ for which $B$ does satisfy that equation?

Comment: How are the functions $A(\cdot,\cdot)$, $B(\cdot,\cdot)$, and $C(\cdot,\cdot)$ defined?

Comment: When you are done thinking, please study [our guide to new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). Following those guidelines will do wonders in avoiding negative attention!

Comment: @amWhy Thanks for saving me the trouble to need to think of more appropriate tags!

Comment: Thanks Jyrki! :)

Comment: The area of the triangle ABC should be $0$.

Comment: Looks like this may be a trick question :-)

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the area of the triangle using determinant?

Comment: Yes, I do Debabrata

Comment: I think for no value of $K$, $A,B ,C$ are collinear.

Comment: Yes. I too think so

Comment: @S.Nep As $K$ varies, $(K/2, K/3)$ traces out a line (call it $L$). Now, by construction the equation $2x - 3y = 5$ corresponds to the line $AC$ through $A$ and $C$. As you say, for any given $K$, the point $(K/2,K/3)$ does not satisfy you equation $2x - 3y = 5$. What does that mean say, geometrically, about the lines $L$ and $AC$?

Comment: So you are done. Write it down on your question about how much do you understand the problem?

Comment: You are correct.  There is no value of $K$ that satisfies the equation.  You should have put your conclusion in the question at the beginning, so people would know what your thinking is.

Comment: $L$ and $AC$ are parallel lines as mentioned by @peter a g. Hence there is no value of $K$ for which the point $B$ can lie upon the line $AC.$

Comment: @saulspatz to be fair, the title suggests what the OP's thinking is...

Comment: @peterag Maybe, but I think he may have gotten the right answer and not realized it was a trick question.

Comment: "Looks like this may be a trick question :-)"  Only if you consider "none" and "never" to be trick answers.  I don't.  The question was "for what values is this true".  And the answer "none" is perfectly acceptable.  That's a far cry from a question being "wrong".

Comment: @fleablood Of course "there is none" is a valid answer - so from that point of view, the question is not a trick question. But do you have an example of a trick question then? If someone asks me, when did I stop stealing candy from the children on my street?  The answer is never.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter these are not functions, but a notation for points. $A$ is the point $(1, -1)$ etc. (I do not like the notation, but it is wide-spread at some places.)

Comment: Trick questions are deliberately misleading.  THis I don't think is.  I think the point is it's okay be be suckered in into trying to solve $2(\frac K2) - 3(\frac K3) = 5$.  I was suckered into trying to solve it.  But when discovering "Hey. That becomes $0=5$ there's no solution!" the result isn't meant to a consternated "WTF!!!! THAT'S IMPOSSIBLE!!!  I'M FREAKING OUT!!!!!" but instead a simple realization that that just means there is no such value of $K$.

Answer (score 7):

> "The equation of line AC is 2x-3y=5. But the point B doesnt satisfy the equation."

WHy not?

If that *is* the equation of the line and if we are told that $(\frac K2, \frac K3)$ is a point of the line, then it must be true that $2*\frac K2 - 3*\frac K3 = 5$.  For what value of $K$ is that true?

1) *Is* that the equation of the line?

The slope of the equation of the line is $m = \frac {C_y - A_y}{C_x - A_x} = \frac {1-(-1)}{4-1} = \frac 23$  so the equation is $(y-A_y) = m*(x-A_x)$ so $y-(-1) = \frac 23(x-1)$ or $y = \frac 23 x -\frac 53$ or as you put it $2x - 3y = 5$.

2) What value of $K$ satisfies $2*\frac K2 - 3*\frac K3 = 5$ ?

$K - K = 5$

$0 = 5$

There is no value of $K$ that satisfies.

So the answer to "For what value of K are the points A(1, -1), B(K/2, K/3), and C(4, 1) collinear?" is...

"None".

Which is a *perfectly* acceptable and valid answer.  Just because a textbook asks a question doesn't mean that there is an valid answer.  But in this case "none" *is* a valid answer.  Just because a textbook asks "when does this occur" doesn't mean the answer isn't "never".

Comment: I don't think "none" is a valid answer to a question of the form "For what value of K ... ?". It would be a valid answer if "value" was plural: "For what values of K ... ?". Using the singular form implies that there is exactly one value; and is not a valid question if there are no values or more than one value.

Comment: Generally speaking I agree with your comments on none being a valid answer. For which I upvoted. However I want to add that the textbook is partially at fault here as well. "For what value P" carries an implication that there is a unique value satisfying P, whereas a phrasing like "For what values P" carries no such implications (to my ears anyway). So while I certainly agree that "there is no such value," is unambiguously the correct answer to the question the textbook poses, I think it would be fair to note that the textbook's phrasing suggests that answer would have to be wrong.

Comment: Mmmm.... In general "What value K where whe $(aK, cK)$ is on the line $y = mx + b$" is solvable by $cK= maK + b$ so $K = \frac b{c-am}$ will have one solutions.  When $c=am$ are special exceptions where if $b =0$ there are infinite solutions an $b\ne 0$ there are none, are cases the student should be expected to be aware of and able to respond to.  So I accept it.  I suppose it's valid to say it is misleading.  But it's not anything that should run up the psychology bills 20 years later.

Answer (score 0):

If can you can proof that no real number $K$ will lead to a point $B$ which is on the line through $A$ and $C$, that is fine.

It might be an error in the book or for educational purposes.

**My attempt:**

The line through $A$ and $C$ is
$$
(1-\lambda) A + \lambda C \quad (\lambda \in \mathbb{R})
$$
We equate with point $B$ and get
$$
(1 - \lambda) (1, -1) + \lambda (4,1) = (K/2, K/3)
$$
which gives the system
$$
(1 - \lambda) + 4 \lambda = K/2 \\
-(1-\lambda) + \lambda = K/3
$$
which is equivalent to the inhomogeneous system in unknowns $\lambda$ and $K$:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rr|r}
3 & -1/2 & -1 \\
2 & -1/3 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & -1/6 & -2 \\
2 & -1/3 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & -1/6 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 5
\end{array}
\right]
$$
We subtract the second row from the first row, then subtract two times the first row from the second row. The resulting last row is inconsistent ($0\cdot \lambda + 0 \cdot K = 5$), so there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

The direction vector of the straight line $K(1/2,1/3)$ is obviously parallel to the direction vector $C-A=(3,2)$ of the straight line through $A$ and $C$.